# Non-square matrix transpose with shared mem in CUDA

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, transpose, gpu-shared-memory

I was trying to get a variation of the CUDA [matrix transpose sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/6_Performance/transpose) for all kind of sizes. Briefly, I have to take an input array (`double *a`) and write it on two different parts (you will notice the different offsets) of a bigger matrix (`double *tab`). I'm storing the data in row-major format so I'm using this macro for indexing:

```
#define IDX2L(i,j,ld) (((i)*ld))+(j)) // 0 based index +row-major format
```

This is the simple code I use.

```
__global__ void cuda_a_Coalesced(double *tab, int tab_rows, int a_rows, double *a)
{
    __shared__  double tile[16*(16+1)]; 
    int col = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    int col_2, row_2;
    int a_cols=tab_rows-a_rows; // tab_rows-a_rows is the number of columns of a
    int tab_cols=2*tab_rows+2;  // 2*tab_rows+2 is the number of columns of tab

    if( (col<a_cols) && (row<a_rows) ) 
    {
        // Load the data into shared mem
        tile[threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*(16+1)]=a[IDX2L(row,col,a_cols)];

        // Normal copy (+ offsets)
        tab[IDX2L(row,col+tab_rows+a_rows,tab_cols)]= tile[threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*(16+1)];

        // New idx
        col_2 = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.x;
        row_2 = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.y;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if( (row_2<a_cols) && (col_2<a_rows) )
        // Transpose (+ other offsets)
        tab[IDX2L(row_2+a_rows,col_2+tab_rows,tab_cols)]= -tile[threadIdx.y+threadIdx.x*(16+1)];

}
```

The launching parameters are the followings:

```
b1=(int)ceil((float)a_cols/16);
b2=(int)ceil((float)a_rows/16);
dim bck(b1,b2):dim th(16,16);

cuda_a_Coalesced<<<bck,th>>>(tab,tab_rows,a_rows,a);
```

Normal copy is always well performed regardless of the size. Transpose copy only works for that sizes that are integer multiple of the block size (as in the CUDA sample). When transpose copy fails, some parts of the operations are right and others not, on a way that I can not exactly predict or track.  Note as the idea is to change the index in the shared memory so that the transpose can be written in a coalesced form in the output matrix (due to row major-format).

Someone could tell me the reason why the code only works with that kind of sizes?

Is there any trick to solve this situation?

Comment: are you sure the code is correct ? at first glance it seems that for some threads col_2 and row_2 might be undefined

Comment: Before this version I tried to put the operations that involve col_2 and row_2 within the first if statement, obviously after the __syncthreads(), but I got the same problem. That was what you were refering to?

Comment: no I mean for those threads for which the condition '(col<a_cols) && (row<a_rows)' does not hold, col_2 and row_2 will be uninitialized. Maybe you should intialize col_2 = MAX_INT, row_2 = MAX_INT so that the next condition "(row_2<a_cols) && (col_2<a_rows)" only holds for correct threads

Comment: it seems that the problem had to do with that you mentioned. I tried your option but the problem didn't disappear. However, going on with your assumptions I've tried another initialization:

    int col_2=blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.x;
    int row_2=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.y;

by doing that and deleting the homonimous compute that had place within the if statement I finally got the code working well, so problem solved!!

Comment: @engineerH: Please add how you fixed your problem as an answer and accept it. This marks the question as answered and complete and also might help the next person who comes along with the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to some undefined threads because the value for `col_2` and `row_2` was being assigned within an `if()` statement that no all threads were visiting.

To solve this situation we can give the value for `col_2` and `row_2` when we declare these variables and delete the homonimous compute that had place within the mentioned `if()`:

```
__shared__  double tile[16*(16+1)];

int col = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

int col_2 = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.x;
int row_2 = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.y;

int a_cols=tab_rows-a_rows; 
int tab_cols=2*tab_rows+2;
```

Thus, the rest of the code looks like this:

```
if( (col<a_cols) && (row<a_rows) ) 
{
    // Load the data into shared mem
    tile[threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*(16+1)]=a[IDX2L(row,col,a_cols)];
    // Normal copy (+ offsets)
    tab[IDX2L(row,col+tab_rows+a_rows,tab_cols)]= tile[threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*(16+1)];
}
__syncthreads();

if( (row_2<a_cols) && (col_2<a_rows) )
    // Transpose (+ other offsets)
    tab[IDX2L(row_2+a_rows,col_2+tab_rows,tab_cols)]= -tile[threadIdx.y+threadIdx.x*(16+1)];
```