# Matrix Transpose (with shared Memory) with arbitary size on Cuda C

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, transpose, gpu-shared-memory

I can't figure out a way to transpose a non-squared matrix using shared memory in CUDA C. (I am new to CUDA C and C)

In [this blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) an efficient way was shown how to transpose a matrix (coalesced transpose via shared memory). But it only works for squared matrices.

Also Code is provided on [github](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/blob/master/series/cuda-cpp/transpose/transpose.cu) (same as on the blog).

On StackOverflow there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208982/non-square-matrix-transpose-with-shared-mem-in-cuda). There `TILE_DIM = 16` is set. But with that implementation every thread just copies one element of the matrix to the result matrix.

This is my current implementation:

```
__global__ void transpose(double* matIn, double* matTran, int n, int m){
    __shared__ double tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];
    int i_n = blockIdx.x*TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
    int i_m = blockIdx.y*TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y; // <- threadIdx.y only between 0 and 7

    // Load matrix into tile
    // Every Thread loads in this case 4 elements into tile.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i += BLOCK_ROWS){
        if(i_n < n  && (i_m+i) < m){
            tile[threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x] = matIn[n*(i_m+i) + i_n];
        } else {
            tile[threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x] = -1; 
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i += BLOCK_ROWS){
        if(tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y+i] != -1){ // <- is there a better way?
            if(true){      // <- what should be checked here?
                matTran[n*(i_m+i) + i_n] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y+i];
            } else {
                matTran[m*i_n + (i_m+i)] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y+i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where 4 elements are copied from a thread into the tile. Also four elements from the tile are copied back into the result matrix.

Here the Kernel-Configuration `<<<a, b>>>`:

```
where a: (ceil(n/TILE_DIM), ceil(n/TILE_DIM))  (-> is casted to doubles) and 
      b: (TILE_DIM, BLOCK_ROWS) (-> (32, 8))
```

I am currently using the `if(tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y+i] != -1)`-statement to determine, which thread should copy to the result matrix (There might be another way). As for my current knowledge, this behaves as follows: In a block, the thread index `(x, y)` copies the data into the tile and the thread index `(y, x)` copies the data back into the result matrix.

I inserted another `if`-statement to determine where to copy the data, as there are 2(?) possible destinations, depending on the thread index. Currently `true` is inserted there, but i tried many different things. The best I could come up with was `if(threadIdx.x+1 < threadIdx.y+i)`, which transposes a `3x2`-matrix successfully.

Can someone please explain, what I am missing by writing back into the result matrix? Obviously only one destination is correct. Using

```
matTran[n*(i_m+i) + i_n] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y+i];
```

as on the blog mentioned should be correct, but I can't figure out, why it is not working for non-squared matrices?

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted doesn't work when `nx != ny`, presuming that both are divisible with `TILE_DIM`? I believe the part where you fill `tile` should be the same as with the code you posted, since transposing happens *after* `__syncthreads`. The `tile` array simply holds a single tile, which means that if `i_n` and `i_m` are within the input bounds, it must be filled with correct data without any `if`s. Shouldn't the kernel configuration be `(n/TILE_DIM, m/TILE_DIM)`?

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer. Both Kernel Configurations are correct. `(n/TILE_DIM, m/TILE_DIM)` only works for `nx` and `ny`, which are divisible by `TILE_DIM`. The kernel configuration `(ceil(n/TILE_DIM), ceil(n/TILE_DIM))` ensures that we have more threads available if `nx` or `ny`are NOT divisible by `TILE_DIM`, so this does just provide us some extra threads, which may be never used. I removed all `if`s as you mentioned and the code didn't work as excepted. Everything besides `nx != 32` and `ny != 32` did not transposed the matrix. I just over complicated a lot. But it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was overcomplicating the problem. [Here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/), the indeces are NOT swapped as i thought. They are recalculated using the Y- and X-Coordinate of the Thread/Block. Here is the snippet:

```
i_n = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;  
i_m = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
__global__ void transposeGPUcoalescing(double* matIn, int n, int m, double* matTran){
    __shared__ double tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];
    int i_n = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
    int i_m = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y; // <- threadIdx.y only between 0 and 7

    // Load matrix into tile
    // Every Thread loads in this case 4 elements into tile.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i += BLOCK_ROWS){
        if(i_n < n  && (i_m+i) < m){
            tile[threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x] = matIn[(i_m+i)*n + i_n];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    i_n = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x; 
    i_m = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;

    for (i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i += BLOCK_ROWS){
        if(i_n < m  && (i_m+i) < n){
            matTran[(i_m+i)*m + i_n] = tile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + i]; // <- multiply by m, non-squared!

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950966/matrix-transpose-with-shared-memory-with-arbitary-size-on-cuda-c#comment94741856_53950966) comment for noticing the error :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to speed-up your kernel even more then, you can use "Shared Memory Bank Conflicts" as shown here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/

Simply, changing the tile initialization with this will help a lot:

```
__shared__ float tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM+1];
```