# How to transpose a huge arbitrary matrix in cuda using shared memory?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, transpose

I have a task to transpose a matrix in CUDA using shared memory with no bank conflicts. The limits are: with*height <= 10^8. The key test sizes are: 1x10^8, 10^4x10^4, 10^8*1.

I have tried a solution provided here [Matrix Transpose (with shared Memory) with arbitary size on Cuda C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950966/matrix-transpose-with-shared-memory-with-arbitary-size-on-cuda-c) but it did not help me, because my matrix size is too large and outside of CUDA dimension limits (65536 blocks and 32 threads per block).

I tried to create a loop, that helps to work with huge matrix:

```
const int BLOCK_DIM = 32;
__global__ void transposeMatrixFast(double* inputMatrix, double* outputMatrix, int width, int height)
{
    __shared__ double temp[BLOCK_DIM][BLOCK_DIM+1];

    int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int offsetx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int offsety = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;

    for (int y = yIndex; y < height; y += offsety)
    {
        for (int x = xIndex; x < width; x += offsetx)
        {
            if ((xIndex < width) && (yIndex < height))
            {
                int idx = y * width + x;

                temp[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = inputMatrix[idx];
            }

            __syncthreads();


            if ((x < width) && (y < height))
            {
                int idx = x * height + y;

                outputMatrix[idx] = temp[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting a "time limit exceeded" error on a testing server. The reason is that I can't use a benefit of a shared memory in this line:
`outputMatrix[idx] = temp[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];` and my kerner slows down. I think there is another way to organise my loop, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to organise my loop, and now I can transpose matrices of ANY size:

```
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 32;
__global__ void matrixTransposeSolveBankConflicts(const double *d_a, double *d_b, const unsigned long rows, const unsigned long cols) {

    __shared__ double mat[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE + 1];

    unsigned long bh = ceil((double)rows / BLOCK_SIZE);
    unsigned long bw = ceil((double)cols / BLOCK_SIZE);

    for (unsigned long blocky = blockIdx.y; blocky < bh; blocky += gridDim.y) {
        for (unsigned long blockx = blockIdx.x; blockx < bw; blockx += gridDim.x) {
            unsigned long bx = blockx * BLOCK_SIZE;
            unsigned long by = blocky * BLOCK_SIZE;

            unsigned long i = by + threadIdx.y;
            unsigned long j = bx + threadIdx.x;

            if (i < rows && j < cols)
            {
                mat[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = d_a[i*cols + j];
            }

            __syncthreads();

            unsigned long ti = bx + threadIdx.y;
            unsigned long tj = by + threadIdx.x;

            if (tj < rows && ti < cols)
            {
                d_b[ti*rows + tj] = mat[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];
            }

            __syncthreads();
        }
    }
}
```